# program for PC-to-phone using Gtalk?

Tags: debian, chat, messaging, empathy

I know I can configure empathy to voice chat between gmail users. But is it possible to make PC-to-phone voice calls with empathy or do I have to use Google's browser plugin?

Does any program support both things? (The point being that I would much prefer using a program listed in the Debian repository rather than having to use a browser with a plugin.)

Comment: The issue with this is that unless you find software that will make use of a modem and you plug in a connected phone line (which sort of defeats the purpose) your call will need to be relayed through a third party server, which is why it requires a service provider (such as google).  The phone system is not on the internet ;)